# Dividing an equation by a vector

Tags: vectors

I am given the two equations

$$\bar{x} \times \bar{b} = \bar{a}$$
$$\bar{a} + \bar{x} = \lambda\bar{c}$$

I multiple the second by $\bar{b}$:

$$\bar{a} \times \bar{b} + \bar{x} \times \bar{b} = \lambda\bar{c} \times \bar{b}$$

and substitute the first one:

$$\bar{a} \times \bar{b} + \bar{a} = \lambda\bar{c} \times \bar{b}$$

divide to get $\lambda$ by itself:
$$\frac{\bar{a} \times \bar{b} + \bar{a}}{\bar{c} \times \bar{b}} = \lambda$$

and substitute back into the second equation and subtract $\bar{a}$:

$$\bar{x} = (\frac{\bar{a} \times \bar{b} + \bar{a}}{\bar{c} \times \bar{b}})\bar{c} - \bar{a}$$

However I'm told the answer is:

$$\bar{x} = (\frac{|\bar{a} \times \bar{b} + \bar{a}|}{|\bar{c} \times \bar{b}|})\bar{c} - \bar{a}$$

Where did the modulus come from? I'm guessing it's something to do with dividing by vectors?

Comment: echnically, you can't divide vectors by vectors since vector "multiplications" are different from scalar multiplication. However, one can divide scalars, especially to find a scalar: $\bar{u}=c\bar{v} \implies ||\bar{u}||=...$

Comment: @Patterns_43, could you expand on that? like what do you mean by ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see that
$$a\times b+a=\lambda c\times b$$
implies two vectors are collinear. Hence you can write
$$\lambda=\pm\frac{|a\times b+a|}{|c\times b|}$$

Answer (score 0):

A "sort of" way to divide cross products: identities like
$$ a\times d = (x\times b) \times d = (x\cdot d) b - (b\cdot d) x$$
for various values of $d$ (e.g. $b$ or $c$).

I tried working out the details, and it did get rather fiddly.  But I think it can be done, and you might prefer it if you worked it out yourself.